# Sending shutdown messages to all clients from server

Tags: linux-networking, rhel6, centos6.5

I'm trying to find a way to broadcast a shutdown message to all the users on clients connected to my centos server. The wall command sends only to users logged into the server and not to clients .I know also of rwall but can't seem to find it on centos 6 or a package that provides it .Is there a cleaner way to do this in rhel/centos 6 .

Comment: The rpm is here rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/2394494/dir/redhat_6.x/com/… for rhel . Use yum to install it .Still testing it though

Comment: How does this answer the question? If you write a self-answer, please don't give intermediate reports. If you found a solution, give the complete, working instructions.

Comment: This rpm is the solution. It's already documented though not particularly for centos. It's just a simple command called rwall. It's usage is documented http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rwall1.html

Answer (score 0):

`Shutdown` includes an optional message paramater

http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown

So if I wanted to restart in 60 minutes and notify all my users I would use

```
shutdown -r +60 Attention all Linux Users, the system will need to be restarted for maintenance soon!
```